# .NET replace non-printable ASCII with string representation of hex code

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string with some non-printable ascii characters in it, something like:

```
"ABCD\x09\x05\r\n"
```

I want to replace these characters with a ascii string representation of the hex code numbers, so I get something like this:

```
"ABCD[09][05][0D][0A]"
```

Whats the best way to do this? Can a regex be used?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The pattern `\p{Cc}` matches any control character, so

```
Regex.Replace(input,
              @"\p{Cc}", 
              a=>string.Format("[{0:X2}]", (byte)a.Value[0])
            );
```

would also replace control characters.

Comment: nice. simple and easy to follow.

Comment: Note that you can't easily reverse this back into the original message as "ABCD[09]\x09\x05\r\n" would result in "ABCD[09][09][05][0D][0A]".  You'd want to escape opening brace (typically using "[[" so that my example would become "ABCD[[09][09][05][0D][0A]"

Comment: @Tom West: That doesn't solve the problem. To reverse your escaped test, you'd also have a problem if the source contains "[[09]]", for example. There is no algorithm I can think of that would allow for a forward-character string replacement as well as a reverse-to-source process using a single string.

Answer (score 8):

```
string s = "ABCD\x09\x05\r\n";
var replace = 
    s.Select(c => Char.IsControl(c) ? ((int)c).ToString("X2") : c.ToString())
     .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, t) => sb.Append(t))
     .ToString();
```

Sorry, no compiler handy, but I think this compiles and does the job.

Also, this kind of walks the string twice (once to project each character to a hex replacement or a string, and then again to aggregate), and you can avoid this by lumping the projection into the call to `Enumerable.Aggregate`, but this is more clear and it probably doesn't matter that much unless this is performance-critical.

Comment: Aghh. Beat me by a few minutes. Confirmed working via LINQPad.

Comment: +1; Great example code.  Now I've got a foothold into finding uses for `Aggregate` :)  I'd personally push the select function into a local delegate, tho, for readability.

Comment: Is there any benefit in using `Aggregate` instead of `String.Join`?

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by Jason's example, but a bit simpler. I'm not sure which performs better, and don't have the time to benchmark it right now, but it should do everything in just one pass:

```
string s = "ABCD\x09\x05\r\n";
string replace = String.Concat(s.Select(c => Char.IsControl(c) ?
                                             String.Format("[{0:X2}]", (int)c) :
                                             c.ToString()));
```

I've tested this for functionality.