# Replace non printable character with octal representation in C++/CLI

Tags: regex, c++-cli

I need to replace any non printable character with its octal representation using C++/CLI.  There are examples using C# which require [lambda or linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034659/net-replace-non-printable-ascii-with-string-representation-of-hex-code).

```
// There may be a variety of non printable characters, not just the example ones.
String^ input = "\vThis has internal vertical quote and tab \t\v";
Regex.Replace(input,  @"\p{Cc}", ???  );

// desired output string = "\013This has internal vertical quote and tab \010\013"
```

Is this possible in with C++/CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can do it inline.  I've used this type of logic.

```
// tested
String^ input = "\042This has \011 internal vertical quote and tab \042";
String^ pat = "\\p{C}";
String^ result = input;
array<Byte>^ bytes;

Regex^ search = gcnew Regex(pat);
for (Match^ match = search->Match(input); match->Success; match = match->NextMatch()) {
    bytes = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(match->Value);
    int x = bytes[0];

    result = result->Replace(match->Value
        , "\\" + Convert::ToString(x,8)->PadLeft(3, '0'));
}

Console::WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", input, result);
```